# Displaying of values on each seaborn sub-barplot

Tags: python, seaborn

I know the similar questions are posted already, but I could not modify my code :(

I have four datasets with the same column names, and I am trying to add the y_value, which is average_referral_sent on each subplot. Can anyone please help?

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2, sharex=True, sharey=True,figsize=(10,10))

sns.barplot(x="split_test_group", y="average_referral_sent", hue='split_test_group',
                 palette=["C0", "C1", "C2"],data=with_in_a_week,ax=ax1)

sns.barplot(x="split_test_group", y="average_referral_sent", hue='split_test_group',
                 palette=["C0", "C1", "C2"],data=between_7_and_14_days,ax=ax2)

sns.barplot(x="split_test_group", y="average_referral_sent", hue='split_test_group',
                 palette=["C0", "C1", "C2"],data=between_14_and_21_days,ax=ax3)

sns.barplot(x="split_test_group", y="average_referral_sent", hue='split_test_group',
                 palette=["C0", "C1", "C2"],data=after_a_month,ax=ax4)

ax1.set(xlabel='Experiment Groups', ylabel='Average Number of Referrals Sent')
ax2.set(xlabel='Experiment Groups', ylabel='Average Number of Referrals Sent')
ax3.set(xlabel='Experiment Groups', ylabel='Average Number of Referrals Sent')
ax4.set(xlabel='Experiment Groups', ylabel='Average Number of Referrals Sent')

plt.show()
```

Here is my output below, and I want to display y="average_referral_sent" from each dataset into related subplots
[image]

Comment: Can you show what is your output and expected output?

Comment: Edited my post. Please check

Comment: Let me see if I get it, you want to the display the actual height of each bar (average_referral_sent) of every plot, don't you?

Comment: It is working but values are not in the middle of bars.
I have tried this, but it is only centering the middle bar value
```
ax1.text(xlocs[i], y + 1, str(y),color='black', ha="center")
```
How can I center the values?

Comment: Do you mean in the middle of the Y-axes, or in the middle of the x-axes?

Comment: I want to display the actual height of each bar (average_referral_sent) on the top of each bars, but in the center of each bar. They are shifting to the right :( @jcaliz

Comment: Understand, well this highly depends of the plot widths, I quick formula might be to adjust the text based on the length of the string and the width, so this case, full plot's width is 10 so each is around 5, I would do the following:  `width = 5` and then `ax.text(xlocs[i] - len(str(y))/(width*5),  y + 0.5, str(y)))` where the other `5` is just a scaling number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the locs of the x-axes, and use `Axes.text`. This is for the first plot, try to replicate for the others

```
xlocs = ax1.get_xticks()
for i in range(len(xlocs)):
    y = with_in_a_week.iloc[i].average_referral_sent

    # you might need to adjust the 0.2 to get the right position
    ax1.text(xlocs[i], y + 0.2, str(y))
```